# How to get a string response from HTTP GET request in nodejs to a varaible using request-promise

Tags: node.js

I want to call web service and get the string response to a variable. here is my code. but the value assign to the variable is 'undefined'. Could anyone please help me.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function web() {
  return request("https://8f41d5af.ngrok.io/webhook/testRequest")
    .then(function(response) {
      return JSON.parse(response);
    });
}

function main() {
  var y;
  web().then(function(result) {
    y = result;
  });
  console.log('response from server=>' + y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should printing your variable after it has been set

```
function main() {
  var y;
  web().then(function(result) {
    y = result;
    console.log('response from server=>' + y)
  });
  // this line executes before the value is set as it is set asynchronously 
  //console.log('response from server=>' + y)
}
```

You also ensure proper chaining of promises.

```
function web() {
  return request("https://8f41d5af.ngrok.io/webhook/testRequest")
    .then(function(response) {
      //return JSON.parse(response);
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(response));
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that also. it didn't return anything. once i debug the code I found  web().then(function(result) {
    y = result;
  });      this part is not executing. Do you have any idea on it. please

Comment: I have updated my answer with proper promise chaining.